# How to put "i" into a loop in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm trying loops a bunch of buttons as below. I understand how loops work, but I'm not sure how to change the numbers below to 'i's in the loop if it were something like:

```
for (var i:Number=1; i<=10;i++){ }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
eyes1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, eyes1action);
function eyes1action(event:MouseEvent):void{
    eyes.gotoAndStop(1);
}
eyes2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, eyes2action);
function eyes2action(event:MouseEvent):void{
    eyes.gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question directly, you can do something like this:

```
for (var i:int = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    this['eyes' + i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:MouseEvent):void {
        eyes.gotoAndStop(i);
    });
}
```

However, this is an awful idea. It would be better to assign a variable e.g. `tf` to each button and use that instead, with a single more generic handler. For example:

```
eyes1.tf = 1;
eyes2.tf = 2; // etc
```

Then:

```
function handleClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var frame:int = event.target.tf;
    eyes.gotoAndStop(frame);
}
```

And obviously:

```
eyes1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleClick); // etc
```

Comment: This implies that these are `dynamic` objects, but `SimpleButton` is not. Adding properties is not necessarily possible. Alternatively, the association from an `eye` to an `int` can be done with a `Dictionary` or a custom class for the buttons if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `SimpleButton` and then add properties. Listener's function who created like this never remove.